# What signal is emitted in response to moveToThread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I am trying to use QThread's in the [proper way](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).

For performance reasons I would like to keep the thread running and push work blocks to it.

The *started* signal is emitted when the thread begins, but what signal is emitted when the QObject is moved to the thread, such that it can begin executing work in the new thread?

Comment: That's what `QtConcurrent::run` is for. No need for `QObject` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such signal. After you have called `moveToThread`, you can use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) to call a function in a different thread *(assuming the thread has been started already)*.

There is a good example how to use it in the docs I linked to above:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(thread, "quit",
                          Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

You can also create a function for your classes that you wish to move to another thread, and call `moveToThread` and emit your own signal in this function:

```
void MyClass::myMoveToThreadFunction(QThread *thread)
{
   moveToThread(thread);
   emit threadChanged(); 
}
```